# Having trouble implementing _str_() method and making it run in the cmd

Tags: python, django, api

I firstly wrote down the method to make the object more human friendly to read but it does not work when I run my object in cmd. Just was after I ran the django built in API. `python manage.py shell` . Yet it still gives this result back when I run `Question.objects.all()` when I run it, it returns `<QuerySet [Question: Question object]>` Where my result should return `<QuerySet [<Question: What's up?>]>` . Please help me resolve this issue.

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


 # Create your models here.
 class Question(models.Model):
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
def _str_(self):
    return self.question_text



  class Choice(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
def _str_(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

Comment: `__str__` not `_str_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
def _str_(self):
    .....
```

with:

```
def __str__(self):
    .....
```

Double underscores, instead of single ones.

Comment: I tried that but when I ran it give me NameError: name 'Question is not defined'

Comment: Shot it. it works thanks! :)